# Add nested child Fragments to layout with non-unique parent IDs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that has a layout with non-unique IDs (the layout repeats itself multiple times). For example:

```
LinearLayout (vertical)
    FrameLayout (id = R.id.always_the_same)
    FrameLayout (id = R.id.always_the_same)
    FrameLayout (id = R.id.always_the_same)
```

I can't make the IDs unique because they are loaded from an XML file individually.

For each of the FrameLayouts, I would like to add a child fragment inside. I tried to call the following multiple times from the outer fragment's `onCreateView` method, but it added all of the child fragments to the first FrameLayout.

```
this.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.always_the_same, MyChildFragment.newInstance(), "tag")
      .commit();
```

How can I specify which FrameLayout to add the fragment to? Or am I going about this all wrong and should be using something other than nested Fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a workaround:

In the outer fragment's `onCreateView` method, instead of adding the fragments directly, I added placeholder layouts with unique IDs to the FrameLayouts. Then in the outer fragment's `onStart` method, I used those unique IDs to add the fragments.